# How can I combine this 2 statement become one

Tags: vb.net

I have 7 different region and with different quantity target set. I want to put in if else statement but now I couldn't find a way to combine my statement into one. I am repeating my function. How can I combine this 2 if else statement to become one? If not my coding will be keep repeating and become very long.

```
    Dim quantity As Integer = 0
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For y = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            quantity += CDbl(dt.Rows(y).Item(3))
        Next

        If Empty = False Then
            Session("outputData") = Nothing
            gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
            gvOutput.DataBind()

            outputSave.Visible = False

        Else
            For y = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                If dt.Rows(y).Item(7).ToString = "Malaysia" Then
                    If quantity >= 50 Or quantity < 50 And dt.Rows(y).Item(8).ToString <> "" Then
                        count += 1

                        dt.Columns(6).ColumnName = "Date"
                        Session("outputData") = TryCast(dt, DataTable)
                        Session("outputData4Search") = Nothing
                        messErrorOutput.Text = ""
                        'Bind Data to GridView
                        gvOutput.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath)

                        Try
                            messErrorOutput.Text = ""
                            gvOutput.DataSource = dt
                            gvOutput.DataBind()
                            gvDisplayOutput.DataSource = CType(Session("outputData4Search"), DataTable)
                            gvDisplayOutput.DataBind()
                            outputSave.Visible = True
                            gvDisplayOutput.Visible = False
                            lblOutputCount.Text = ""
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            messErrorOutput.Text = "Please upload correct format of excel template file."
                            outputSave.Visible = False
                            gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
                            gvOutput.DataBind()

                        End Try
                    ElseIf quantity < 50 And count = 0 Then

                        messErrorOutput.Text = "Please insert remarks in template file."
                        Session("outputData") = Nothing
                        gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
                        gvOutput.DataBind()

                        outputSave.Visible = False
                    End If
                End If

                If dt.Rows(y).Item(7).ToString = "Singapore" Then
                    If quantity >= 90 Or quantity < 90 And dt.Rows(y).Item(8).ToString <> "" Then
                        count += 1

                        dt.Columns(6).ColumnName = "Date"
                        Session("outputData") = TryCast(dt, DataTable)
                        Session("outputData4Search") = Nothing
                        messErrorOutput.Text = ""
                        'Bind Data to GridView
                        gvOutput.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath)

                        Try
                            messErrorOutput.Text = ""
                            gvOutput.DataSource = dt
                            gvOutput.DataBind()
                            gvDisplayOutput.DataSource = CType(Session("outputData4Search"), DataTable)
                            gvDisplayOutput.DataBind()
                            outputSave.Visible = True
                            gvDisplayOutput.Visible = False
                            lblOutputCount.Text = ""
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            messErrorOutput.Text = "Please upload correct format of excel template file."
                            outputSave.Visible = False
                            gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
                            gvOutput.DataBind()

                        End Try
                    ElseIf quantity < 90 And count = 0 Then

                        messErrorOutput.Text = "Please insert remarks in template file."
                        Session("outputData") = Nothing
                        gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
                        gvOutput.DataBind()

                        outputSave.Visible = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gadzin mentioned a function to cope with the repeating blocks. Your higher level `If` issue can be solved by using `Select`

```
        Dim totalCount as Long = 0
        For y = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Select Case dt.Rows(y).Item(7).ToString
                Case "Malaysia"
                    totalCount =+ DataSomething1(50, y, dt.Rows(y).Item(8).ToString)
                Case "Singapore"
                    totalCount =+ DataSomething1(90, y, dt.Rows(y).Item(8).ToString)
                Case Else
                    '[...]
            End Select
        Next y
```

Using a modified function with a signature like:

```
Private Function DataSomething1(TestingValue As Integer, rowNum as Long, otherDataPoint) As Long

    Dim quantity As Integer = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0

        If quantity >= TestingValue Or quantity < TestingValue And otherDataPoint <> "" Then
            count += 1
            '[.... Some relevant code here]
        ElseIf quantity < TestingValue And count = 0 Then
            '[.... Some relevant code here]
        End If
    End If
    Return count
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use function if you see repeated "codeblocks" in your program

```
Private Function DataSomething(country As String, TestingValue As Integer)

    Dim quantity As Integer = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    If dt.Rows(y).Item(7).ToString = country Then
        If quantity >= TestingValue Or quantity < TestingValue And dt.Rows(y).Item(8).ToString <> "" Then
            count += 1

            dt.Columns(6).ColumnName = "Date"
            Session("outputData") = TryCast(dt, DataTable)
            Session("outputData4Search") = Nothing
            messErrorOutput.Text = ""
            'Bind Data to GridView
            gvOutput.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath)

            Try
                messErrorOutput.Text = ""
                gvOutput.DataSource = dt
                gvOutput.DataBind()
                gvDisplayOutput.DataSource = CType(Session("outputData4Search"), DataTable)
                gvDisplayOutput.DataBind()
                outputSave.Visible = True
                gvDisplayOutput.Visible = False
                lblOutputCount.Text = ""
            Catch ex As Exception
                messErrorOutput.Text = "Please upload correct format of excel template file."
                outputSave.Visible = False
                gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
                gvOutput.DataBind()

            End Try
        ElseIf quantity < TestingValue And count = 0 Then

            messErrorOutput.Text = "Please insert remarks in template file."
            Session("outputData") = Nothing
            gvOutput.DataSource = Nothing
            gvOutput.DataBind()

            outputSave.Visible = False
        End If
    End If


    Return somestuffifyouneed
End Function
Private Sub YourSub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles something

    DataSomething(singapore, 50)
    DataSomething(Malaysia, 90)
End Sub
```

Comment: Its just genereded at my VS for testing. Just use 
DataSomething(singapore, 50)
DataSomething(Malaysia, 90)
Put those in sub you were having the code you pasted

Comment: I might not explained it right. So this code you posted is in some sub you are having right? Make Function outside this sub that you'll name whatever you want (like Function DataSomething(country As String, TestingValue As Integer)) and put in this function repeating code. Country and TestingValue are local Values that are used initialized in other Sub. Like if you put DataSomething(England, 50) then in code it will use string ="England" and integer 50 as initalized variable (the only variables that change in repeating code) in function that you can us in other Subs in this Class.

Comment: In other words like if you have 
private Sub askn(,,) handles button1.click and 10 times repeated something like this 
For x in item
A = 50+10
next
Where only numbers 50 and 10 change for like 11 and 12 and then 23 and 99 and only value you need is A then use function to make it like
function ADD(number1 as integer, number2 as integer)
result=number1+number2
return result
end function